# Not able to change JVM options ( xmx, xms etc. ) with openjdk:8 based docker container

Tags: java, docker, adoptopenjdk

I am trying set xmx and xms parameters for my java application which is inside docker container. When I try with adoptopenjdk it works fine.

With AdoptOpenjdk

Dockerfile :

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8-openj9:alpine
WORKDIR /
ADD /target/*.jar app.jar
...
```

Docker compose

```
  myapp:
    image: myapp:dev
    container_name: myapp
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "PORT:PORT"
    environment:
      - OPENJ9_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx1400m -Xms1400m -XX:+UseContainerSupport
```

[image]

But the same thing is not working with openjdk:8

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR /
ADD /target/*.jar app.jar
...
```

Docker Compose file

```
  myapp:
    image: myapp:dev
    container_name: myapp
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "PORT:PORT"
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1400m -Xms1400m -XX:+UseContainerSupport
```

[image]

Comment: First question - is the environment variable actually set in the container?  I'd check that directly, rather than inferring whether it's set by memory performance graphs.

Comment: I am using docker compose file to set environment variables. This works in case of adoptopenjdk but not with openjdk8. Even tried with this command java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -Ei "maxheapsize|maxram" by doing docker exec.

Comment: Did you check?  Because that's what I actually asked.